# In chrome packaged apps, Is there a way to declare multiple sandboxes, each one having its own content security policy?

Tags: manifest, google-chrome-app, sandbox, content-security-policy

I need to have sandboxes totally secured, others more "relaxed".

I tried this in the `manifest.json` (doesn't work, but describes accurately what I need to do):

```
...,

"sandbox": [
    {
    "pages":[
      "sandbox1.html"
      ],
    "content_security_policy": "<strict csp...>" 
    },

    {
    "pages":[
      "sandbox2.html"
      ],
    "content_security_policy": "<relaxed csp...>" 
    }
]
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to have **more than one** content security policy for sandboxed pages.

The  [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/sandbox) shows how to implement the **same** CSP for multiple sandbox pages, but not how each sandbox could have its own CSP.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's not possible; `"sandbox"` is an object and can only have one `"content_security_policy"` key.

Sounds like an idea for a feature request.